# Mulesoft Dataweave, LDAP to SOAP large message truncating at certain size. Size limit?

Tags: java, soap, ldap, mule, dataweave

(question tldr at end)

So my task for the Mule "Transform Message" component is to take a bunch of user info from LDAP Directory Service and provide it to an old database endpoint using SOAP. Fairly simple transform stuff.

The main ! about this operation is the size of the message that has to be provided to the endpoint. The entire payload has to be provided in a single message, otherwise the service will remove all entries that are not part of the payload (there is no explicit 'delete' service). This is an issue because the amount of users in the directory is roughly 20,000 causing every message to be 5MB or so in size.

My flow in Mule Studio currently works with a low amount of users being returned from the LDAP component. Successful return from the endpoint and I can see the data updated in the legacy environment. When applying this to a more 'production-realistic' load the Web Service Consumer (SOAP) craps out with an odd exception (unexpected EOF/character).

[image: message flow]

So I stuck a File component in the middle to dumpcheck the message that was being sent to the Consumer. The message is indeed getting cut before it can finish, which is where the EOF is coming from.

This is the transform script in Dataweave.

```
%output application/xml 
%namespace ns0 test.namespace.com
---
{
    ns0#updateContact: {
        ns0#ContactType: "Primary",
        ns0#ContactDetails: {
            (payload map {
                (ns0#ContactDetailElem: {
                    ns0#personID: $.personID,
                    ns0#contactDetail: $.desc
                }) when $.personID != null
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output is below and successfully occurs with a lesser payload.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<ns0:updateContact xmlns:ns0="test.namespace.com">
  <ns0:ContactType>Primary</ns0:ContactType>
  <ns0:ContactDetails>
    <../>
    <ns0:ContactDetailElem>
      <ns0:personID>{Integer}</ns0:personID>
      <ns0:contactDetail>{String.detail}</ns0:contactDetail>
    </ns0:ContactDetailElem>
    <../>
  </ns0:ContactDetails>
</ns0:updateContact>
```

On the big payload the following happens at the end of the file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<ns0:updateContact xmlns:ns0="test.namespace.com">
  <ns0:ContactType>Primary</ns0:ContactType>
  <ns0:ContactDetails>
    <../>
    <ns0:ContactDetailElem>
      <ns0:personID>{Integer}</ns0:personID>
      <ns0:contactDetail>{String.detail}</ns0:contactDetail>
    </ns0:ContactDeta
```

Which looks like a typo but is what looks like the message being cut before it can finish. The file size is always stopped at 3,553,099 characters. Of course this makes the flow crap out as the xml is invalid.

The question then is there a limit on the message size that the Dataweave transformer can create? If not a legitimate bug but a configuration issue, where would I find this setting? I've had a look around but can't find anybody encounter this type of issue.

**TL;DR: Do Dataweave transform messages have a size limit around 3.38MB?**

**Exception caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog**

PS: I've found the documentation on dataweave streaming after typing this up, will see if this can help my situation. Otherwise i'm considering implementing a workaround to construct the message outside dataweave and then passing it to the Consumer.

Comment: why not use a custom java transformer?

Comment: I mean sure, I could define my own class to do the transform and message but it kinda defeats the purpose of integrating via Mule does it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Mule version 3.8.3? Try 3.8.4, it fixed a bug in DataWeave which caused cutoff of Strings in some cases.

Comment: Switching the runtime to 3.8.4 resolves the issue. Payload is no longer being truncated.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem, same as yours that is with the problem of size. We implemented streaming using stax.